# Unable to start CouchDB

Tags: couchdb

Just installed CouchDb using brew on mac mountain lion. Everything went well till I hit the following issue to start the server I do not know erlnag and could not analyze the dump file

```
`couchdb
Apache CouchDB 1.2.1 (LogLevel=info) is starting.
{"init terminating in do_boot",{{badmatch,{error,{bad_return,{{couch_app,start,[normal,["/usr/local/etc/couchdb/default.ini","/usr/local/etc/couchdb/local.ini"]]},{'EXIT',{{badmatch,{error,shutdown}},[{couch_server_sup,start_server,1,[{file,"couch_server_sup.erl"},{line,98}]},{application_master,start_it_old,4,[{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,274}]}]}}}}}},[{couch,start,0,[{file,"couch.erl"},{line,18}]},{init,start_it,1,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]}]}}

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
init terminating in do_boot ()`
```

Any help much appreciated.
I have left the configurations files as it is

Comment: default.ini and local.ini were unmodified?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Often this is due to incorrect permissions on various configuration files & directories. It can be caused by running as a sudo / root user for example.

You can try fixing this using the following, but you may need to either create/add yourself to a couchdb group, or use a different user:group combination.

```
sudo chown -R couchdb:couchdb /etc/couchdb /var/lib/couchdb /var/run/couchdb /var/log/couchdb
sudo chmod -R 770 /etc/couchdb /var/lib/couchdb /var/run/couchdb /var/log/couchdb
sudo find /etc/couchdb /var/lib/couchdb /var/run/couchdb /var/log/couchdb -type f | sudo xargs chmod 660
```

```

See the `chmod` section in http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Installing_on_OSX for more detail.

Comment: How to fix this issue on windows. I am also getting same error but on windows. Note: I have already started DB as a windows service.. I am guessing that as service is already started, when I am trying to run batch script to start DB again.. it is failing.

Comment: Used the three lines of command (without starting from root address in any of the cases) in /usr/local because /var/run/couchdb doesn't exist. /usr/local/var/run/couchdb does. But this didn't fix the issue. Still getting the same error

Comment: Couldn't fix my error when I had read this answer at first place.  Then I have changed 'couchdb' to current session user ( whoami command). After that I was able to run couchdb without root user.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem when attempting to load a configuration file that doesn't exist, I was starting CouchDB with the `-a` option to supply additional configuration, and if that file doesn't exist I get an error similar to the one reported:

```
$ couchdb -a /does/not/exist.ini
{"init terminating in do_boot",{{badmatch,{error,{bad_return,{{couch_app,start,[normal,["/usr/local/etc/couchdb/default.ini","/usr/local/etc/couchdb/local.ini"]]},{'EXIT',{{badmatch,{error,{error,enoent}}},[{couch_server_sup,start_server,1,[{file,"couch_server_sup.erl"},{line,56}]},{application_master,start_it_old,4,[{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,269}]}]}}}}}},[{couch,start,0,[{file,"couch.erl"},{line,18}]},{init,start_it,1,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]}]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install libicu-dev
```

Provide Proper permissions