# CouchDB won't start badmatch error bad_return CentOS7

Tags: centos, couchdb, digital-ocean

I've been trying to install CouchDB on a fresh centos7 in digital ocean droplet. I get no errors trying to install with the following steps:

```
yum -y update
yum -y groupinstall "Development Tools"
yum -y install libicu-devel curl-devel ncurses-devel libtool libxslt fop java-1.6.0-openjdk java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel unixODBC unixODBC-devel openssl-devel


Step 2 - Installing Erlang

wget http://www.erlang.org/download/otp_src_R16B02.tar.gz
tar -zxvf otp_src_R16B02.tar.gz
cd otp_src_R16B02
./configure && make
make install



Step 3 - Installing the SpiderMonkey JS Engine

wget http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/js/js185-1.0.0.tar.gz
tar -zxvf js185-1.0.0.tar.gz 
cd js-1.8.5/js/src
./configure && make
make install


Step 4 - Installing CouchDB

wget http://mirror.olnevhost.net/pub/apache/couchdb/source/1.6.1/apache-couchdb-1.6.1.tar.gz
tar -xvf apache-couchdb-1.6.1.tar.gz
cd apache-couchdb-1.6.1
./configure && make
make install


Step 5 - Setting up CouchDB

adduser --no-create-home couchdb
chown -R couchdb:couchdb /usr/local/var/lib/couchdb /usr/local/var/log/couchdb /usr/local/var/run/couchdb
ln -sf /usr/local/etc/rc.d/couchdb /etc/init.d/couchdb
chkconfig --add couchdb
chkconfig couchdb on


vi /usr/local/etc/couchdb/local.ini
Should you need to access couchdb from the web, in the [httpd] section, look for a setting called bind_address and change it to 0.0.0.0 - this will make CouchDB bind all available addresses.

[httpd]
port = 5984
bind_address = 0.0.0.0

service couchdb start
/etc/init.d/couchdb status (this has no output)
```

And i get the following when i try to run:

```
/usr/local/bin/couchdb
Apache CouchDB 1.6.1 (LogLevel=info) is starting.
{"init terminating in do_boot",{{badmatch,{error,{bad_return,{{couch_app,start,[normal,["/usr/local/etc/couchdb/default.ini","/usr/local/etc/couchdb/local.ini"]]},{'EXIT',{{badmatch,{error,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,couch_secondary_services,{shutdown,{",[]},{couch_uuids,new_prefix,0,[{file,"couch_uuids.erl"},{line,84}]},{couch_uuids,state,0,[{file,"couch_uuids.erl"},{line,100}]},{couch_uuids,init,1,[{file,"couch_uuids.erl"},{line,50}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,304}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}}}}}}},[{couch_server_sup,start_server,1,[{file,"couch_server_sup.erl"},{line,98}]},{application_master,start_it_old,4,[{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,269}]}]}}}}}},[{couch,start,0,[{file,"couch.erl"},{line,18}]},{init,start_it,1,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]}]}}

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
init terminating in do_boot ()
```

Does anyone know how to get past this?

Note I get `no such file or directory` when trying the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14453082/unable-to-start-couchdb)

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if erlang-crypto is a separate module that is maybe not installed?

CouchDB doesn’t (imho rightfully) doesn’t account for distributions splitting up the monolithically released Erlang installation.

Your error is raised in the UUID module and the only thing I can think of immediately is the crypto dependency that might be missing.

Comment: Thanks for the post. I haven't had time to test this yet. A couple days after I asked the question, I switched the server to Ubuntu. I still intend on testing it given centos is preferred for this project.